# ApplicationPath being ignored by wildfly

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly

I'm currently trying to setup my first Java-EE (JDK8) Application and can't get the overriding of the Context Root to work with the `@ApplicationPath` annotation.
The Application server in use is **Wildfly 16.0.0.Final** and I'm trying to use Resteasy as JAX-RS implementation.

Since I'm using gradle to deploy my application as a war this are my dependencies: ( It's a mess and I'm trying to figure out what I really need and what not, advices always welcome )

```
    dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final'
    compileOnly 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.8.2'
    compileOnly 'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0'
    compileOnly 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compileOnly 'javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.2'
    compileOnly 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:2.0'
    compileOnly 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.2.Final'
    compileOnly 'org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.4.2.Final'
    compileOnly 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8'
    compileOnly 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8'
    compileOnly 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.6.3.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'jaxrs-api', version: '3.0.12.Final'
}
```

I verified that wildfly is using an adequate version of resteasy and it is also using 3.6.3.

My Application config looks like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("rest/*")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // Intentionally empty. Just used to configure the application path for wildfly

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(HelloWorldController.class);
        return s;
    }

}
```

Now I am currently able to successfully deploy my application but the context root is still being set to the name of my war file like this:

```
18:39:47,586 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/Rest-Test-1.0' for server 'default-server'
```

When accessing the URL with the war name I can see my log entry of my WebFilter, but The filter is also not being able to correctly perform the chain in addressing it to the correct Class with a matching `@Path` annotation.(Might this also be a Problem with CDI?)

Update 1:
Changing the @ApplicationPath to "/rest" or "rest" doesn't change the context root registration either. It still takes the war name as context root.

TL;DR:
Why is my `@ApplicationPath` annotation being ignored and why is my webfilter not being able to chain the request because of that?

**Solution:**

1. Change dependency from resteasy to compileOnly

This removed the warning `WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher is annotated with @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!`

2. Change ApplicationPath to correct path ("/rest")

This made my URI register correctly as root and enabled for the WebFilter to perform the correct chain, since it now can distinct from each component in the URI.

3. Add jboss-web.xml to the WEB-INF

With the jboss-web.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="10.0"
           xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">

    <context-root>/api</context-root>
    <security-domain>other</security-domain> <!-- Configure to the security domain used for your deployed application -->
    <server-instance>default-server</server-instance>
    <virtual-host>default-host</virtual-host>

</jboss-web>
```

I was able to override the context root to a much more beautiful one.

If your IDE states an error for the server-instance element you can ignore it, it will still work correctly.

Comment: When looking at my configurations, `@ApplicationPath` always has an _actual_ path, not a pattern. The different resources annotated with `@Path` can then have patterns.

Comment: So changing it to just rest should to the trick?

Comment: Well not sure, but maybe worth trying?

Comment: The combination of both answers is actually what made it work. I'm unsure of what to accept to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before posting my solution I first want to credit ogulcan and Sebastian S, since the help of both made me find the correct solution.

**Solution:**

1. Change dependency from resteasy to compileOnly

This removed the warning WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher is annotated with @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!

2. Change ApplicationPath to correct path ("/rest")

This made my URI register correctly as root and enabled for the WebFilter to perform the correct chain, since it now can distinct from each component in the URI.

3. Add jboss-web.xml to the WEB-INF

With the jboss-web.xml like this:

http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">

```
<context-root>/api</context-root>
<security-domain>other</security-domain> <!-- Configure to the security domain used for your deployed application -->
<server-instance>default-server</server-instance>
<virtual-host>default-host</virtual-host>
```

I was able to override the context root to a much more beautiful one.

If your IDE states an error for the server-instance element you can ignore it, it will still work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can change context root using [application xml](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Getting_Started_Guide/beta422/html/Configuration_Files.html)

Comment: But the application.xml is only being used for EAR deployments as far as I know, or am I wrong?. 
Currently I'm only using a WAR deployment since an EAR would be "overpowered" in only a small application with one module.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice. Only war approach you can use [jboss-web.xml](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.1/html/security_guide/jboss-webxml_configuration_reference)

Comment: The combination of both answers is actually what made it work. I'm unsure of what to accept to be honest.